# Problem with BIND9

Tags: dns

I have been fighting with this problem for a long time...

For some unknown reason for me, some addresses seem to don't resolve, when I try

`dig www.google.com.br @localhost`

it returns me:

> ; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> www.google.com.br @localhost ;; global
>   options: +cmd ;; Got answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status:
>   NOERROR, id: 46072 ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY:
>   4, ADDITIONAL: 4
>
> ;; QUESTION SECTION: ;www.google.com.br.             IN      A
>
> ;; ANSWER SECTION: www.google.com.br.      25      IN      A
>   173.194.118.79 www.google.com.br.      25      IN      A       173.194.118.87 www.google.com.br.      25      IN      A       173.194.118.88 www.google.com.br.      25      IN      A       173.194.118.95
>
> ;; AUTHORITY SECTION: google.com.br.          25      IN      NS
>   ns3.google.com. google.com.br.          25      IN      NS
>   ns1.google.com. google.com.br.          25      IN      NS
>   ns4.google.com. google.com.br.          25      IN      NS
>   ns2.google.com.
>
> ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION: ns1.google.com.         27      IN      A
>   216.239.32.10 ns2.google.com.         26      IN      A       216.239.34.10 ns3.google.com.         27      IN      A       216.239.36.10 ns4.google.com.         26      IN      A       216.239.38.10
>
> ;; Query time: 0 msec ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) ;; WHEN: Fri
>   Sep 26 17:46:54 2014 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 245

Everything working fine.

But when I try some specific hosts, like **Hotmail** or **YouTube**, it fails:

```
dig www.hotmail.com @localhost
```

> ; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> www.hotmail.com @localhost ;; global options:
>   +cmd ;; Got answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 56204 ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0,
>   ADDITIONAL: 0
>
> ;; QUESTION SECTION: ;www.hotmail.com.               IN      A
>
> ;; Query time: 44 msec ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) ;; WHEN: Fri
>   Sep 26 17:48:41 2014 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 33

But, if I try `dig +tcp www.hotmail.com @localhost` it works:

> ; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> +tcp www.hotmail.com @localhost ;; global
>   options: +cmd ;; Got answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status:
>   NOERROR, id: 41319 ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY:
>   5, ADDITIONAL: 5
>
> ;; QUESTION SECTION: ;www.hotmail.com.               IN      A
>
> ;; ANSWER SECTION: www.hotmail.com.        23      IN      CNAME
>   dispatch.kahuna.glbdns2.microsoft.com.
>   dispatch.kahuna.glbdns2.microsoft.com. 23 IN A  65.55.85.12
>   dispatch.kahuna.glbdns2.microsoft.com. 23 IN A  157.55.104.76
>
> ;; AUTHORITY SECTION: hotmail.com.            26      IN      NS
>   ns5.msft.net. hotmail.com.            26      IN      NS
>   ns2.msft.net. hotmail.com.            26      IN      NS
>   ns3.msft.net. hotmail.com.            26      IN      NS
>   ns1.msft.net. hotmail.com.            26      IN      NS
>   ns4.msft.net.
>
> ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION: ns5.msft.net.           25      IN      A
>   65.55.226.140 ns2.msft.net.           25      IN      A       208.84.2.53 ns3.msft.net.           25      IN      A       213.199.180.53 ns1.msft.net.           25      IN      A       65.55.37.62 ns4.msft.net.           25      IN      A       208.76.45.53
>
> ;; Query time: 7 msec ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) ;; WHEN: Fri
>   Sep 26 17:49:58 2014 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 291

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a local PC i recommend setting up forwards to your ISP's or even google's NSs, for example:

```
        forwarders {
            8.8.8.8;
            8.8.4.4;
    };
```

and don't forget to add

```
    forward only;
```

to act as forwarder

more more information refer to [Ubuntu's official documentation about configuring caching server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto#Caching_Server)

Comment: Nope. The forwarders were already set. I added the option `forward only;` to see if it works. But still the same behavior

Comment: do you have any rules in your iptables that could effect DNS ports? 'iptables -L' in your terminal

Comment: No. There are no rules in the firewall